# submit bootstrap wizard form to sql database

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing my website using some free bootstrap template and I working with asp.net and c# to implement this website.

The template comes with form wizard template page that has 3 steps with some question in each step. And 3 buttons : next, prev, and finish.

The wizard page template use:

```
<!-- jQuery Smart Wizard -->
<script src="../vendors/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/js/jquery.smartWizard.js"></script>
```

I want to submit the form data into sql database but, i have no control on the finish button and also others buttons.

```
<!-- jQuery Smart Wizard -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wizard').smartWizard();

    $('.buttonNext').addClass('btn btn-success');
    $('.buttonPrevious').addClass('btn btn-primary');
    $('.buttonFinish').addClass('btn btn-default');
  });
</script>
<!-- /jQuery Smart Wizard -->
```

This is my form:

```
<!-- Smart Wizard -->
                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="add_project_form" runat="server" onsubmit="">

                <div id="wizard" class="form_wizard wizard_horizontal">

                    <ul class="wizard_steps">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#step-1">
                        <span class="step_no">1</span>
                        <span class="step_descr">
                                          Step 1<br />
                                          <small>General Information</small>
                                      </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#step-2">
                        <span class="step_no">2</span>
                        <span class="step_descr">
                                          Step 2<br />
                                          <small>Assign User</small>
                                      </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#step-3">
                        <span class="step_no">3</span>
                        <span class="step_descr">
                                          Step 3<br />
                                          <small>Create Project</small>
                                      </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>


                    <div id="step-1">

                      <!-- Project Name -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="project_name">Project Name <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <asp:TextBox id="project_name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- PI name -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="pi_name">PI Name <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <asp:TextBox id="pi_name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                   </div>

           <div id="step-2">

                      <!-- Assign Developer dropdown -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Assign Developer</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="developers_DropDownList" runat="server" Width="100px">
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                   </div>


                    <div id="step-3">
                       <p>
                            Click on 'Finish' to create the new database.
                       </p>

                    </div>


                </div>
                <!-- End SmartWizard Content -->

              </form>
```

I know how to submit form data using the button "onclick" function in c#. but here, i dont have access on the buttons. how can i submit my form in this case?

I can show you the "jquery.smartWizard.js" file but it huge.

**For clarification:**
I don't know what is the proper way to submit the form in this case.
1- I s it ok to put the code of insert data into database in PHP file and call it from action=" " in the form tag? 
2- Or can I put the code of insert data into database in c# function? in this case how can I call this function from my asp file and how to pass form data to this function?
3- Or can I use js function to insert data into database?

**Remember:** I don't have control of Finish button

Comment: document.getElementById("add_project_form").submit();

Comment: @Bimal Das Do you mean to put action=" " in the form tag? Then? where to place the code for saving into the database? in php file or c# file or javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm assuming this problem has been fixed but for anyone else having problems I'll try an cast a bit of light on the solution or at least a partial solution.

Firstly your intention was to insert data from an HTML form to a database. 
Your HTML form looks like this:

```
     <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="add_project_form" runat="server" onsubmit="">
```

If you have a web application handling this form it should be making a "post" request to the backend like so:

```
    <form class="whatever-your-using" id="whatever-you-like" action="/handle-html-form" method="post">
```

This will make a post to the server/app point to the route /handle-html-form which should have a function which takes the data from the form and save it to the database.

Obviously, you need to has a submit button in order to actually send the form. My approach was to download the smartWizard.js and had it to my own project

I then edited the file to suit my purpose. For example here is a small snippet of the code change.

Original smartWizard.js:

```
    function SmartWizard(target, options) {
    this.buttons = {
       next : $('<a>'+options.labelNext+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonNext"),
       previous : $('<a>'+options.labelPrevious+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonPrevious"),
       finish  : $('<a>'+options.labelFinish+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonFinish")
    };
```

My smartWizard.js:

```
    function SmartWizard(target, options) {
    this.buttons = {
      next : $('<a>'+options.labelNext+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonNext"),
      previous : $('<a>'+options.labelPrevious+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonPrevious"),
      finish: $('<a>' + options.labelFinish + '</a>').attr({
        type: 'submit',
        name: 'buttonFinish',
        value: 'Submit'
    }).addClass('buttonFinish')
};
```

I've added the attributes for the submit button directly to the finishButton. This was the first solution i found to get around the problem.

Its worth mentioning that the whole of the HTML for the smartWizard must be nested inside a form element. Otherwise, all the element from each step of the wizard would be saved. 
Here is a HTML example to clearify what im trying to say:

```
    <form class="whatever" id="whatever" action="/handle-html-form" method="post">
      <div class="form_wizard wizard_horizontal" id="wizard">
      // Then all the steps below but still inside the form
```

Hope this helps